# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'protocol') after deployed on vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, vite, vercel

I am using axios to get the data from an API:

```
 const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(API_ENDPOINT)
      const res = await response.data;
      console.log(res);
      setMovie(res.results);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

I am using vite as a bundler so the environment variable created can be accessed by:

`const API_ENDPOINT = import.meta.env.VITE_URL;`
It was fetching the data in when running in *local environment*. But **after the deployment** on vercel. It is not fetching the data and showing:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'protocol').

I was before fetching the API with *fetch* and it is doing the same thing.

Comment: `await` is not needed in `const res = await response.data;`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your questions, I can simply guess that the error occurs because an object is not being "import", reference, or "require" correctly. For example, if "axios" is not being reference correctly, it will be undefined.

Try debugging and see if the error occurs before `const response = await axios.get(API_ENDPOINT)` by writing a few tests.

Another way to solve the problem is to establish a database.

Comment: Can you explain on how can I reference axios correctly ?

Comment: By reference, I mean `import axios from "axios"` or `const axios = require("axios")`

What I am saying here is that the object or reference can still be undefined even if you have the code written down correctly. There maybe a compatibility issue. That is why it is important to write test case and know which line the error is being produced.